# Display all days in specific month for data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create a table that displays all days of a given month, and then check if this day is in the database, if it displays the necessary data for a given record
at the moment i have loop for display all days for month:

```
def example_table(request,pk,month):
    something = database.filter(name__pk=pk,date__month=month).all()
    num_days = monthrange(2021, month)[1]
    num_days = range(1,num_days+1)
    context = locals()
```

in template i was add something like that:

```
{%for time in num_days%}
{%for x in something%}
{%if x.day == time%}
table
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

but this record is repeated x times.
Someone can give me some advice how to do that ?
should looks like

```
1 data data data
2 
3
4 data data data
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```py
from itertools import groupby

def example_table(request,pk,month):
    something = database.filter(name__pk=pk,date__month=month).order_by("date__day")
    day_wise_data = {day: tuple(data) for day, data in groupby(something, key=lambda each: each.date.day)}
    num_days = monthrange(2021, month)[1]
    num_days = range(1,num_days+1)
    day_wise_data = [day_wise_data.get(day, tuple()) for day in num_days]
    context = {"day_wise_data": day_wise_data}
```

```
<tr>
<th>Day</th>
<th colspan="100%">Day Data</th>
</tr>
{%for data in day_wise_data%}
<tr>
<td>{{ forloop.counter + 1 }}</td>
{% for obj in data %}
    <td> {{ obj.whatever }} </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```